# How to get metadata / schema of mongodb with all field name and its type in python / pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am looking for a **python** solution where so far I used **pymongo** and able to retrieve databases, collections. Now it is a challenge to fetch field name and its type. Most of the solution I found on internet suggests to iterate on each document and determine. It would be better if any other optimised solution is available.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.